# MEMB memory allocation in Contiki

Tags: networking, dynamic-memory-allocation, contiki

In Contiki I declared a linked list like this:

```
MEMB(recv_memb, struct record, MAX_RECORD);
LIST(recv_list);
```

After using the linked list I free the allocated memory like this:

```
for(n = list_head(recv_list); n != NULL; n = n->next)
{     
    list_remove(recv_list,n); 
    memb_free(&recv_memb,n); 
}
```

but after reaching the MAX_RECORD the node restarts, How do I free the memory for another 30 records?

I'm simulating a networking scenario in Contiki Cooja simulator and the code is a combination of Contiki programming and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem (not sure if this will solve your issue completely...) is that you access the `n->next` pointer in the statement `for(n = list_head(recv_list); n != NULL; n = n->next)` after the element is already removed from the list and it's memory freed.

Try this instead:

```
void *next;
for(n = list_head(recv_list); n != NULL; n = next)
{     
    next = n->next;
    list_remove(recv_list,n); 
    memb_free(&recv_memb,n); 
}
```